# How can I boot Ubuntu from a USB drive on a Windows XP computer?

Tags: boot, live-usb

My computer is a Microsoft Windows XP Media Center Edition 2005. I followed the directions to create a bootable USB using the [Linux Pendrive Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) at [Ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows). I have tried editing the boot hierarchy to boot from USB first, but the computer simply boots with Windows like normal. Do you have any suggestions? I simply want to use Ubuntu without having to permanently install it.

Comment: So your bios supports booting from usb, you have set and saved the boot order in the bios to boot from usb first,turned off computer  and put in the usb turned the computer on but boots from hard drive into windows still?

Comment: Does your BIOS has anything USB related in the boot options? Does it boots in another system?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, push F10 > system configuration > boot options > boot order > ***USB Diskette on Key/USB Harddisk*** (put this at the top) 
F10 again and save/exit

That should to my knowledge boot the USB drive before anything else on the computer including the Windows OS

Answer (score 0):

1) Did you md5sum check the downloaded iso?
  See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM
  Check the number against the listing in the link for your release listed at
  http://releases.ubuntu.com under the MD5SUMS link.
If that's your problem, redownload the iso and try again.  Once you have the good iso,
check the media you create, and check your pc memory.
2) Did you select the media check before trying to install?
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck
3) Did you ever do a "memory check" (another live-media menu choice) on your PC?
Doing the above can save you a lot of time struggling with a bad install media.

All good, now you should be able to boot and "Try" successfully.